# Are tensorflow random-variables only created once per sess.run?

Tags: tensorflow

If I have something like this:

```
a = tf.random_uniform((1,), dtype=tf.float32)
b = 1 + a
c = 2 + a
```

Will `a` be the same or different when calculating `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 3):

Every time a `sess.run()` is executed, different results are generated, as can be seen in the official documentation of [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/constant_op).

For example, given the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.random_uniform((1,), dtype=tf.float32)
b = 1 + a
c = 2 + a
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(a))
print(sess.run(b))
print(sess.run(c))
print(sess.run(a))
```

It will produce different values of a and hence the values of b will be *1 + a (new generated)*
where a(new generated) will be different from a.

**Output:**

```
[ 0.13900638]   # value of a
[ 1.87361598]   # value of b = 1 + 0.87361598(!= a)
[ 2.81547356]   # value of c = 2 + 0.81547356(!= a)
[ 0.00705874]   # value of a(!= previous value of a)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful (both of you)!

Answer (score 1):

As answered by [@heena bawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063671/3027854)

For every sess.run() the values will be re initialised.

To solve for that problem, we initialise the session and call run once. If multiple results are expected then they are passed in a list as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.random_uniform((1,), dtype=tf.float32)
b = 1 + a
c = 2 + a
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([c, b, a]))
```

output:

```
[array([2.0236197], dtype=float32), array([1.0236198], dtype=float32), array([0.02361977], dtype=float32)]
# c is 2.023..
# b is 1.023..
# a is 0.023..
```